# Issues of informal definition of limits

Tags: limits

I'm going through Thomas' Calculus and one of the exercises asks:

> Show by example that following statement is wrong:
>
> *The number $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$ if $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$ as $x$ approaches to $c$.*
>
> Explain why the function in your example does not have the given value of $L$ as a limit $x\rightarrow c$

I can't find any holes in the informal definition. Maybe $f(x)=L$ would be a violation of the informal definition because it doesn't get closer to $L$ (whatever $c$ is) - it just stays the same?

Comment: Well, maybe $f(x)=L$ would be the better example. I think you've hit on the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, changed 1 to $L$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just "gets closer" is not enough, because it might not get arbitrarily close: consider for example $f(x)=x^2,c=0,L=-1$.

On the flip side, even if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L$, you still might not have $f(x)$ getting closer to $L$ as $x \to c$ if in fact $f(x)=L$ for various $x$'s arbitrarily close to $c$. For example you could have $f(x)$ is equal to $L$ everywhere, then of course $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L$ but this informal definition would say the opposite, since the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ is the same everywhere.

Comment: Such an $L$ wouldn't qualify as a limit, even by the informal definition, would it?

Comment: @AdrianKeister $x^2$ does get closer to $-1$ as $x$ approaches $0$. It just never gets any closer than a distance of $1$.

Comment: Ah, so the formal definition says the limit doesn't exist, and the informal says it _does_ exist.

Comment: @Ian: Oh, I see. You're right.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Actually in my first example $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2$ does exist, but it isn't $-1$. Thus if you accept my slightly weird interpretation of the informal definition, it has the bad property that its notion of the limit is non-unique. The second problem I mentioned is definitely there; the first problem only really shows up if you are being a bit pedantic about the meaning of the informal definition (but still, this is precisely the sort of place where such pedantry is warranted).